# Trying to use prepared statement with ILIKE operator

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

So I'm trying to update a calendar with the new event title that is entered by the user through comparing the old title and updating it with the new one. Here is the code

```
$result = pg_prepare($conn, "event_update", "UPDATE calendar.calendar SET title = $1 WHERE title ILIKE $2");

$result = pg_execute($conn, "event_update", array($titleNew,$titleOld);
```

This says that I'm not returning the right number of paramaters for my prepared statement.

$titleOld now holds 'title' but nothing is being changed and this works inside postgres, just not in the php.

Comment: [How can I use prepared statements with LIKE operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990965)

Comment: What these `" ' "` things are for?

Comment: so that the ILIKE doesn't compare it to a column instead it compares it to the name of the title. Trying to concatenate on the single quotes

Comment: What is `ILIKE` Do you mean `WHERE I LIKE ...`

Comment: Why don't you add them to first parameter then? Please read from the link above how prepared statement works

Comment: the ILIKE operator just makes it case insensitive...

Comment: I used the example inside the article and it's still not working. The edits are reflected in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You missed \ character for parameters in the string.

```
$result = pg_prepare($conn, "event_update", "UPDATE calendar.calendar SET title = \$1 WHERE title ILIKE \$2");
```